# How do I populate the Django table django_site in a yaml fixture?

Tags: django

I'm trying to populate the `django_site` table in my test database with the following yaml content:

```
- model: django.contrib.sites.site
  pk: 1
  fields:
    domain: stackoverflow.com
    name: Stack Overflow

- model: django.contrib.sites.site
  pk: 2
  fields:
    domain: serverfault.com
    name: Server Fault
```

I'm following the [Django doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/) on how to do the above.  I also know that `django_site` model is located in `django/contrib/sites/models.py`.  The exception that I am getting from the above after running `python manage.py test myapp` is:

```
DeserializationError: Invalid model identifier: 'django.contrib.sites.site'
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the whole module path, just the app name. So it should be

```
model: sites.site
```