# How do I populate the Django table MyApp_user_groups in a yaml fixture?

Tags: python, mysql, django, fixtures

My question is very similar to [How do I populate the Django table django_site in a yaml fixture?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1312468/4078830) , but I need some help on this.

I create a group in auth_group table in my YAML fixture:

```
- model: auth.Group
  pk: 1
    fields:
    name: admin
```

In my MySql I have a Django table named: `MyApp_user_groups`, where MyApp is the name of the Django app; this table is automatically created by Django. This table should connect `MyApp.User` model (created by me) to the Groups model of Django. 
Using a YAML fixture, I want to add a tuple in that table (for the purpose of add a user to a group automatically when I run `syncdb`), but I receive the following error:

```
DeserializationError: Invalid model identifier: MyApp.User_Groups
```

So the code is

```
- model: MyApp.User_Groups
  pk: 1
    fields:
    user_id: 2
    group_id: 1
```

I'm a newbie with Django.
Any ideas?

Comment: did you use uppercase u or lowercase u for 'User_Groups' ? looks like a spelling error to me. what is the name of your model? it should by yourapp.yourmodel name. So pay attention to the case of U and G.

Comment: MyApp_user_groups is a many to many table created by django. This table  should connect MyApp.User model (created by me) to the Groups model of django.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Django >= 1.7 (with migrations) you could (and should) use Data Migrations.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

```
def create_group(apps, schema_editor):
    Group = apps.get_model("auth", "Group")
    g = Group.objects.create("Your group name")
    UserGroup = apps.get_model("MyApp", "User_Group")
    UserGroup.objects.create(user_id=2, group_id=g.id)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('MyApp', '0001_initial'),
        ('auth','0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_group),
    ]
```